# Automatically split a huge TeX file into smaller files

Tags: awk, latex, tex

How would I automatically split the sections or chapters of a huge TeX file into many smaller TeX files?

This somewhat works:

```
awk -v RS='\\chapter{' '{print "\\chapter{"$0 > (NR".tex")}' huge_tex_file.tex
```

…although for some reason it puts a `\` at the end of every output file except the last one.

Comment: See [Splitting a large txt file into 200 smaller txt files on a regex using shell script in BASH](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4952021/914686) or [Split one file into multiple files based on delimiter](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11313852/914686).

Comment: please provide huge_tex_file.tex